# how to add dropdown arrow to sidenave bootstrap

Tags: html, dropdown, sidenav

I'm new to bootstrap and I've been working on a sidenav. Unfortunately the documentation on the bootstrap website didn't include much about side navs. I've been working on it but I can't get the arrow to show up on the dropdown options. Where is it supposed to be added? In the a tag?

```
<script>$(document).ready(function () {

$('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
});</script>




     <span style="font-size:20px;cursor:pointer"><button type="button" class=""btn btn-dark" data-toggle="button" aria- 
   pressed="false" autocomplete="off" id="sidebarCollapse">menu</button></span>
   <div class="wrapper">
<!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar">


    <div class="sidebar-header">

    </div>

    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#home" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Media</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="home" data-parent="#sidebar">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>

            <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Resources</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu" data-parent="#sidebar">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <a href="#page" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><font color=lightblue>Other</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="page" data-parent="#sidebar">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">other links</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you put the screen shot of your UI

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a property to collapse on button click, you can use this

```html
<span style="font-size:20px;cursor:pointer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-toggle="collapse" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" id="sidebarCollapse" data-target="#collapse1">menu</button></span>
    <div id = "collapse1" class="wrapper">
   <ul class="list-unstyled components">
   <li class="active">
    <a href="#home" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Media</a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="home" data-parent="#sidebar">
     <li>
      <a href="#">Home 1</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Home 2</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Home 3</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Resources</a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu" data-parent="#sidebar">
     <li>
      <a href="#">Page 1</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Page 2</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Page 3</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
    <a href="#page" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><font color = "lightblue">Other</a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="page" data-parent="#sidebar">
     <li>
      <a href="#">other links</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Page 2</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Page 3</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```